# Type Error: ord() expected string of length 1, but int found

Tags: python, python-3.x

Подскажите, почему при использовании следующего кода:

```
s = b'\xcd\x86a task\x04\x84 you'
prefix = ord(s[0])
```

выскакивает эта ошибка:

> Type Error: ord() expected string of length 1, but int found

Как возможно исправить?

При это, если сделать:

```
s = '\xcd\x86a task\x04\x84 you',
```

то код работает.

Comment: s[0] уже int, поэтому в ord смысла нет -  у вас же двоичная строка. просто `prefix = s[0]`

Answer (score 1):

Потому что при индексировании объекта `bytes` оно  возвращает целое число

**Пример 1**

```
s = b'\xcd\x86a task\x04\x84 you'
prefix = s[0]
print(prefix)
```

**Пример 2**

```
s = '\xcd\x86a task\x04\x84 you'
prefix = ord(s[0])
print(prefix)
```

похожий вопрос на [английском StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19897209/troubleshooting-typeerror-ord-expected-string-of-length-1-but-int-found)